# How to embed AsyncTask inside a service

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask

I am trying to call this class which extends `AsyncTask` inside a service

```
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
    /**
     * getting All products from url
     */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    latb = c.getString(TAG_LATITUDE);
                    lngb = c.getString(TAG_LONGITUDE);

                    Double lal = Double.parseDouble(latb);
                    Double lol = Double.parseDouble(lngb);

                    double dist = docar(lal, lol);

                    if (dist < 2000) {
                        Intent dfsjk = new Intent(GetFindService.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(dfsjk);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // no products found
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

I call this as follows

```
new LoadAllProducts().execute();
```

Should I declare the class seperately or how do I call it successfully without crashing the app?

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried? There is nothing preventing you from using an `AsyncTask` inside a `Service`. However, if you need to perform just one task on one thread (other than the main), consider using an `IntentService` instead. From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html):

> IntentService is a base class for Services that handle asynchronous
>   requests (expressed as Intents) on demand. Clients send requests
>   through startService(Intent) calls; the service is started as needed,
>   handles each Intent in turn using a worker thread, and stops itself
>   when it runs out of work.